Making a react HOC act as a type guard
I have created a library called conditionalize-component, instead of you having to write something like this:
{ true ? <MyComponent></MyComponent> : null }

You can write
<MyComponent renderIf={true} />

Download from npm here
Now the problem is TypeScript does not know that this should be a type guard, for example if you have this code, TypeScript will give an error because it will think icon is undefined:
<Div renderIf={!!props.icon}>
  <props.icon /> {/* <---- type error, icon could be undefined! */}
</Div>

Here's my code:
This is the higher order component creator callled withConditionals, you give it any component, and it wraps it with a higher order component that has the property renderIf (and some others).
First here's the main interface:
import type { ReactNode } from 'react'

export interface ConditionalProps {
  renderIf?: boolean
  override?: ReactNode
  fallback?: ReactNode
  excludeChildren?: boolean
}

And here is the withConditionals HOC factory:
import _ from 'lodash'
import type { FC, PropsWithoutRef, Ref } from 'react'
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'
import type { ConditionalProps } from './types'

function withConditionals<P>(OriginalComponent: FC<P>) {
  return forwardRef((props: PropsWithoutRef<P & ConditionalProps>, ref) => {
    const conditionalKeys = ['fallback', 'override', 'renderIf', 'excludeChildren']
    const {
      fallback,
      override,
      renderIf = true,
      excludeChildren = false,
    } = _.pick(props, conditionalKeys)

    const originalProps = _.omit(props, conditionalKeys) as any

    let renderEl: any
    switch (true) {
      case excludeChildren === true:
        renderEl = originalProps?.children
        break
      case renderIf === true:
        renderEl = <OriginalComponent {...(originalProps as P)} ref={ref} />
        break
      case !!override:
        renderEl = override
        break
      default:
        renderEl = fallback
    }

    return <React.Fragment>{renderEl}</React.Fragment>
  })
}

export default withConditionals

You can use it as follows, here are some examples:
import { MyComponent } from '../MyComponent' 
import {} from 'conditionalize-component'
const MyComponentC = withConditionals(MyComponent)

function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponentC renderIf={1 + 1 === 2}> See me when 1 + 1 = 2 </MyComponentC>
      <div>I always render</div>
    </div>
  )
}

Or even with native HTML elements:
export const Button = withConditionals((props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>) => <button {...props} />)

<Button renderIf={true}>Click me</ButtonIf>

How can I let TypeScript know that I am doing Type checking and that this is a Type guard??

Side question, do you find this abstraction and additional overhead valuable enough to forego conventional conditional rendering, e.g. just simply using condition && JSX or condition ? JSX : null? I mean, it's nice and techie and all, but why? It's not like it greatly improves readability, maintainability, or code re-use. FWIW I'd probably ask you to fix this on any Merge/Pull request.

Oh, yes of course, for small parts it wouldn't be very important. But i have worked on a system with lots of permissions and user roles. especially in the pages of "create something" forms, there would be fields that are hidden, visible based on other fields as well as the logged in user role and system settings. at first I wrote the code with normal style true && true && true ? : null but then it quickly became a nightmare especially for components where you want their children to be rendered but you don't want their wrapper to be rendered. I found this way a lot easier to maintain and read

I don't know how to explain it, but it's a bit like when to use if/else statements and when to use switch/case blocks.

I see. For "conditional wrappers" I've typically also used conditional rendering, assigning a wrapper to a variable, i.e. const Wrapper = condition ? Layout1 : React.Fragment; or something similar, then applied normal JSX later, i.e. <Wrapper> .... </Wrapper>.

@DrewReese, yes using this you can directly write <Layout1 excludeChildren={!condition}> ...content... </Layout1>

No, I got and understood that part of the code. I still don't think the abstraction is a worthwhile replacement to a line or two of conditional/ternary logic, but I'll follow this question because I do find it a bit interesting. Good luck though, I hope you are able to find a solution to your question.
